# How do i create a string enum types without overriding toString method to be used in Mule Studio?

Tags: java, enums, mule, connector, mule-studio

I'm working with Mule Studio in this, and I actually was wondering the possibility to add the drop down list with a "custom" string name. The case applies for MIME Types (ContentTypes) names. (i.e: text/css, text/javascript, and so)

Made an structure like this:

```
public enum HttpContentType {
        TEXT_PLAIN 
        {
            public String toString() {
                return "text/plain";
            }
        },
        TEXT_CSS
        {           
            public String toString() {
                return "text/css";
            }   
        },
        TEXT_JS
        {
            public String toString() {
                return "text/javascript";
            }   
        },
        TEXT_XML
        {
            public String toString() {
                return "text/xml";
            }   
        },
    };
```

To then be used like this as a Configurable attribute:

```
/**
     * Connection Content Types
     */
    @Configurable
    @Placement(order=1,group="Configuration",tab="HTTP Configuration")
    private HttpContentType contentType;
```

But of course that when reading that from the Mule Studio it will be a Drop Down list with names such as: `TEXT_CSS`, `TEXT_XML`, `TEXT_JAVASCRIPT` ( http://puu.sh/3vLbd.png ) and so instead of `text/css`, `text/xml`, `text/javascript`.

How can i achieve this result?

Answer (score 3):

A far better way to achieve this would be to provide a field in your enum, and provide an appropriate constructor:

```
public enum HttpContentType {
    TEXT_PLAIN("text/plain"),
    TEXT_CSS("text/css");

    private String value;

    HttpContentType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    } 

    public static HttpContentType getByValue(String value){
        for (final HttpContentType element : EnumSet.allOf(HttpContentType.class)) {
            if (element.toString().equals(value)) {
                return element;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way.  Then all you need is to override toString() once and have it return this.value.

Comment: Yeah that would work i undestand but Mule doesn't take it. Don't know why it takes the enum names and doesn't care about the methods in it.

Comment: @msqar. Well, I've no idea about the behaviour on Mule.

Comment: @RohitJain :( i don't know how to do this. It's been used in existing mule components but don't know how they achieve that.

Comment: Just for the sake of precision @msqar talks about Mule Studio (an IDE) not Mule ESB.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to provide a different method to get the MIME string.

```
public interface IMimeTypeProvider {
    public String toMimeType();
}

public enum HttpContentType implements IMimeTypeProvider {
    TEXT_PLAIN 
    {
        public String toMimeType() {
            return "text/plain";
        }
    },
    ...

    public String toMimeType() {
        return "text/plain";
    }
}
```

You might also consider adding a `toDisplayString()` method. The enumerator name is not necessarily a good display name, even in a single locale.

Comment: i know your example would work but i need it to work with Mule. Mule looks like doesn't recognize inner methods, overridden methods and so, only the enum physical name "TEXT_XXXX". Think it will work with annotations like FriendlyName(value="text/css") or Mime(value="..."). Going to test this and let you guys know.

Comment: Just for the sake of precision @msqar talks about Mule Studio (an IDE) not Mule ESB.

Comment: @DavidDossot hey again David! :') sup! do you know how to do this? Tried with Mime, FriendlyName annotations, overriding methods, nothing works as of yet. Have on idea how to achieve this. Too bad about the official Mule Documentation! tried posting in Mule Forum but no one replies back! :S

Comment: @msqar Sorry, I don't know how Mule Studio works behind the scene so I don't know if it's possible to modify the rendering of enum values. Maybe file an improvement request: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO ?

Comment: Yeah its a nice idea but maybe this IS supported already in Mule and it's not something to implement. :'(

Comment: @DavidDossot lol david, just talked with someone from MuleSoft and told me DevKit doesn't support this as of yet. And it could be a nice feature to add. Cool

Comment: Did you create a JIRA? If not, this nice feature may never be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum HttpContentType {
TEXT_PLAIN("text/plain"), TEXT_CSS("text/css");

private String code;

HttpContentType(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String toString() {
    return code;
}

public static HttpContentType getEnum(String code) {
    if (code.equals("text/plain")) {
        return TEXT_PLAIN;
    } else if (code.equals("text/css")) {
        return TEXT_CSS;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}